# Once and for all: Produce PDF/X-1a:2001 (with lualatex, without pdfx package)

Tags: luatex, pdf, printing

I've been going crazy browsing the internet for an ultimate, easy, straightforward, up-to-date answer (possibly hoping to find some switch for the lualatex command). I also checked the LaTeX 2e manual (that not-so-short one): nothing. Not even on Stackexchange I found an ultimate, easy straightforward up-to-date answer. I hope that not only will someone give this answer, but that this answer will be continuously updated for future reference for others.

So, using the latest LuaLaTeX (with whatever distribution), not using the pdfx package, how does one easily enforce PDF/X-1a:2001 output?

Additionally as a subquestion: how does one verify that it is PDF/X-1a:2001-compliant?

Additionally as a subquestion: how does one set all essential PDF/X-1a:2001 options (that are normally set)?

Comment: Why not `pdfx`?

Comment: Because I've read that it is unstable or that it has unpredicted results.

Comment: I don't agree with every part of pdfx but imho it is currently your best bet if you don't want to add the needed code manually yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. What about switching to ConTeXT? How much of a hassle could it be to use my .tex file with it?

Comment: Though I should perhaps make this a separate question.